# Simultaneous recursion on equivalent graphs using Python

Tags: python, multithreading, recursion, graph, multiprocessing

I have a structure, looking a lot like a graph but I can 'sort' it. Therefore I can have two graphs, that are equivalent, but one is sorted and not the other. My goal is to compute a minimal dominant set (with a custom algorithm that fits my specific problem, so please do not link to other 'efficient' algorithms).

The thing is, I search for dominant sets of size one, then two, etc until I find one. If there isn't a dominant set of size `i`, using the sorted graph is a lot more efficient. If there is one, using the unsorted graph is much better.

I thought about using threads/multiprocessing, so that both graphs are explored at the same time and once one finds an answer (no solution or a specific solution), the other one stops and we go to the next step or end the algorithm. This didn't work, it just makes the process much slower (even though I would expect it to just double the time required for each step, compared to using the optimal graph without threads/multiprocessing).

I don't know why this didn't work and wonder if there is a better way, that maybe doesn't even required the use of threads/multiprocessing, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an algorithm suggestion, then lazy evaluation seems like the way to go.

Setup the two in a data structure such that with a `class_instance.next_step(work_to_do_this_step)` where a class instance is a solver for one graph type. You'll need two of them. You can have each graph move one "step" (whatever you define a step to be) forward. By careful selection (possibly dynamically based on how things are going) of what a step is, you can efficiently alternate between how much work/time is being spent on the sorted vs unsorted graph approaches. Of course this is only useful if there is at least a chance that either algorithm may finish before the other.

In theory if you can independently define what those steps are, then you could split up the work to run them in parallel, but it's important that each process/thread is doing roughly the same amount of "work" so they all finish about the same time. Though writing parallel algorithms for these kinds of things can be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not doing what you describe. Possibly you're waiting for BOTH to finish somehow? Try doing that, and seeing if the time changes.